# UserDefaults are wiping out while installing the different build version of same application from Testflight

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults, testflight

I have an application and a specific version is installed on my iPhone device. Now when I install the different build versions of the same application from the TestFlight, the UserDefaults data is being wiped out(but remains saved in case of the same version). Now I want to know whether It is the default behavior or am I missing something. Also, I want to know the workaround of this behavior.

Comment: This is not possible unless you are changing `BundleID`

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't ideally and never happened before with me. But i am facing this situation now.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. it was being done in the code manually in ApplicationManger and it had nothing to do with the TestFlight.